# XQuery Update to wrap an existing node

Tags: xquery, basex

I'm trying to wrap a node with another new node using XQuery update and I'm stuck in several different errors let me give you a short example:

Initial XML is

```
<a id="test">
  <title>title</title>
</a>
```

XQuery code is:

```
copy $x := db:open('testdb')/a[@id eq 'test']/title 
modify replace node $x 
with <b>{$x}</b> 
return <ok/>
```

I'm using [basex](http://basex.org) as the surrounding database and this is why I'm using the db:open function.

What I want to obtain in the end is

```
<a id="test">
  <b>
    <title>title</title>
  </b>
</a>
```

But I receive an error:

```
[XUDY0009] Target has no parent: element title {...}.
```

Note: the result of query:

```
db:open('testdb')/a[@id eq 'test']/title
```

is

```
<title>title</title>
```

If I modify the query as follows

```
copy $x := db:open('testdb')/a[@id eq 'test']/title 
modify replace node db:open('testdb')/a[@id eq 'test']/title
with <b>{$x}</b> 
return <ok/>
```

then the error is

```
[XUDY0014] Node was not created by copy clause: element title {...}.
```

What is the proper way of doing this kind of update queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the node that’s bound to $x, and return $x:

```
copy $a := db:open('testdb')/a[@id eq 'test']
modify replace node $a/title with <b>{ $a/title }</b> 
return $a
```

In BaseX, the `update` keyword can be used as alternative. It allows for a more compact representation:

```
db:open('testdb')/a[@id eq 'test'] update {
  replace node title with <b>{ title }</b> 
}
```

If you want to update the database node itself, there is no need to use `copy` or `update`:

```
let $title := db:open('testdb')/a[@id eq 'test']/title 
return replace node $title with <b>{ $title }</b>
```

Comment: The first query raises error "[XUDY0009] Target has no parent: element." The  second query raises a syntax erro ron expression on "replace" token :( but the third query works OK.

Comment: I have updated the first two queries. To learn about the differences between updating and non-updating expressions, please have a look at the semantics: http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Update.

Comment: The first example doesn't work IF you use a DECLARE for a$ instead of a COPY-modify a$ syntax as you did. I'm learning and this had me stuck for a bit. The processor just reported error: "unexpected end of query" if I tried to write any more code after it until I got the syntax correct.